# Как убрать горизонтальный скролл?

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка

Каким образом можно убрать горизонтальный скролл, при этом сохранив адаптивность сайта?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
/*GLOBAL*/
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif, Arial;
  color: #332E3C;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
}


a.btn {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 4px 15px;
  transition: background-color .5s;
}

a.btn:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.button {
  background: #067655;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-out;
  float: left;
}

.button:hover {
  background: #23a95c;
}

div .with_triangle {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.with_triangle::before {
  content: '';
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  z-index: -1
}


h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
}

/*HEADER*/
header {
  height: 750px;
  background: url(../images/header_background1200-2.jpg) no-repeat center bottom;
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
  align: center;
}

header a.logo {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url(../images/Teorema_logo_v5.png) no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size: contain;
  top: 26px;
  left: 80px;
}

header a.logo span {
  display: none;
}

header h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
}

header div.hero {
  position: absolute;
  width: 42%;
  top: 230px;
  left: 5%;
}

header div.hero h1 {
  line-height: 1em;
  margin: 0 0 30px 0;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Работа преподавателем математики в онлайн-школе "Теорема" | Работа для математиков</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js\jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/smoothscroll.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700&amp;subset=cyrillic-ext" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Caveat|Open+Sans:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">



</head>



<body>
  <header>
    <a class="logo" title="Teorema. Онлайн-школа по математике" href="#"><span>Teorema</span></a>
    <div class="hero">
      <h1>Онлайн-школа Teorema ищет преподавателей математики по скайпу.</h1>
      <a class="btn" title="Регистрация преподавателя математики" href="#register">Регистрация преподавателя</a>


    </div>
    <a class="arrow-down" style="display:block" href="#about">
      <div class="arrow-down"></div>
    </a>
  </header>
```

Comment: что такое тянучесть? адаптивность?

Comment: Да ) имеел ввиду это )

Comment: Вообще не понятно, откуда горизонтальный скролл берется. Если сделать body { max-width: xxx }, то он исчезнет. Но за скроллом ничего нет

Comment: я бы на вашем месте использовал boostrap, если позволяет задача. там используете `fluid-contanier`

Comment: А без bootstrap можно? Нужно заверстать классическим методом )

Comment: читайте и изучайте https://geekbrains.ru/posts/adaptive_bootstrap

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90252/discussion-between-michael-best-and-nikita-migushev).

Comment: вы бы что ли живой сайт показали. Что-то сильно широкое, что конкретно без просмотра кода сайта сложно сказать. Конкретно в шапке ничего подозрительного не видно.

Comment: Задайте хедеру overflow: hidden и width: 100%